# Refactor nested null checking for multiple possible string values

Tags: c#, xml

I am parsing an XML file and trying to get the guid of a node where it has an attribute `"name"` and a value of `"Name"` like so:

```
<property name="Name" guid="7eca00b3-38e0-f0e8-9b72-2b822b21de6b" />

string propertyGuid = propertyList.Where(x => x.name == "Name").FirstOrDefault()?.ToString();
if (propertyGuid == (object)null)     
     throw new ArgumentNullException();
```

So I just found out that there are nodes that don't have a `"Name"` value but have a `"Code"` value. Which lets me check for another null value again

```
<property name="Code" guid="8bca00b3-38e0-f0e8-9b72-2b822b21de7a" />

string propertyGuid = propertyList.Where(x => x.name == "Name").FirstOrDefault()?.ToString();
if (propertyGuid == (object)null)
{
     propertyGuid = propertyList.Where(x => x.name == "Code").FirstOrDefault()?.ToString();
     if (propertyGuid == (object)null)
          throw new ArgumentNullException();
}
```

How do I refactor my code such that when another criteria (e.g `"ID"`) is introduced in the future, I don't have to make another nested null check?

**EDIT:**

The check should be the other way around.

```
if ((object)propertyGuid == null)
```

Comment: null is null, no need to cast to an object

Comment: Is `x` your custom type with a `name` property because to me it looks a lot like pseudocode.

Comment: @t3chb0t yes, it is generated from an XSD model

Comment: @eurotrash edited the code, it should be the other way around `if ((object)propertyGuid == null)`

Answer (score 4):

You can just go with :

```
// Just check both case at the same time
string propertyGuid = propertyList.Where(x => x.name == "Name" || x.name == "Code").FirstOrDefault()?.ToString();
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyGuid)) // Same check as you did but written differently
{         
    throw new ArgumentNullException();
}
```

Then for the future, I guess that you can have `Guids` on node you don't want to extract. You could have properties on a list or array :

```
List<string> possibleName = new List<string>() {"Code", "Name"};
```

And then calling an extract function :

```
Public static string GetGuid(List<string> possibleName, Whatever propertyList)
{
    string propertyGuid = string.Empty;
    foreach (string name on possibleName)
    {
        propertyGuid = propertyList.Where(x => x.name == name).FirstOrDefault()?.ToString();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyGuid))     
        {
             return (propertyGuid);
        }
    }
    throw new ArgumentNullException();
}
```

Ps : I'd like to add that if `propertyList` is a `NodeList` you won't get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce some code and [IMO] increase readability with the following:

validPropertyValues should come from whatever source you want to manage this - database, config file, constant in code.

```
//valid values in the name property
var validPropertyValues = new List<string> { "Code", "Name" };

//check to see if name contains any of the accepted values
if (propertyList.Any(d => validPropertyValues.Contains(d.name)))
{
    //returns guid from the list. 
    //Using First() will throw an exception if guid doesn't exist

    //option 1
    //If guid will be populated if it exists
    return propertyList.Select(d => d.guid).First();

    //option 2
    //this version is only needed if guid can exist AND be empty
    var guidValue = propertyList.Select(d => d.guid).First();
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(guidValue))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }

    return guidValue;
}
```